# graphic card crashing frequently

Tags: gpu

CPU: I7 4820k @ 3.7Ghz Ram: 32Gb GPU: GTX 970 4Gb gddr5 (EVGA brand) PSU: 875watt OS: Win10 Gigabyte mother board I am running 3 1920x1080 60hz AOC 24' Monitors.

I have had this gpu and psu for a little over a year now, and I have been running wow on High/Ultra since than. Never had an issue, very rarely I would see my frames dip into the low 50s or high 40s. But i have it locked at 60 fps.

recently, the last week or so, when I play wow (or gta 5 and other high graphic demanding games) after a minute or two my card crashes, and I can still hear, but my screens turn off and refuse to turn on cause they do not get a signal. I can sit on facebook, or basic games no problem, its only when graphics get demanding.

The other night when I was on skype with my friend, I was playing gta5, when I tabbed into he said my voice started breaking up, when I tabbed off, I was clear again. Watching specy and evga precision my cards heat is fine (35 idle - 60-70 In wow/gta5) but it is always trying to go over its clocked speed, and when I noticed gta5 finally drop under its base speed, my monitors shut off shortly after.

So I am wondering if I should maybe try overclocking my computer, or try getting another 970 since its SLI ready.

Sidenote: I turned down ALL the settings on wow (super ugly) but it runs and doesnt crash.

Comment: Few words : Overheat. Graphic Card Malfunction. Fan not functioning. Dust Accumulation.

Comment: Well about 2-3 months ago I upgraded the 2 fans I had and even added a third. I also try and clean out my case with cans of air atleast ounces every other week. I think I'm going to take the card out and give it a good cleaning.

Comment: Time for an RMA

Comment: I'll have to dig up the box, should still have it. I hope I don't need to return it but if need be..

Comment: RMA inbound. 
Topic can be closed.